# Is it possible to specify schema.data in a Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.MultiSelectBuilder

Tags: multi-select, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Using server-side filtering, I would like to respond to each request from a kendo MultiSelect widget with an object comprised of multiple properties one of which is the data items to be enumerated in the drop down list.

It looks like I need to specify *schema.data*.  But I haven't figured out how to specify *schema.data* using the MVC wrappers.  Is this possible or is there another way to do this?

Here's my custom MultiSelectBuilder code:

```
MultiSelectBuilder BuildSelector(HubAssemblyFieldEnums.FilterFields field, string placeHolder, string dataValueField, string dataTextField = default(string), string itemTemplate = default(string), string tagTemplate = default(string)) {
    var name = System.Enum.GetName(typeof(HubAssemblyFieldEnums.FilterFields), field);
    var multiSelect = Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
                    .Name(name)
                    .Placeholder(placeHolder)
                    .HighlightFirst(true)
                    .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
                    .AutoBind(false)
                    .DataSource(_ => _.Read(read => {
                        read.Action("getFilterValues", "api/hubassembly")
                            .Type(HttpVerbs.Post)
                            .Data("function(e) { return getFilters(e, filterEnum." + name + "); }");
                    })
                    .ServerFiltering(true));

    if (dataValueField != default(string)) { multiSelect.DataValueField(dataValueField); }
    if (dataTextField != default(string)) { multiSelect.DataTextField(dataTextField); }
    if (itemTemplate != default(string)) { multiSelect.ItemTemplate(itemTemplate); }
    if (tagTemplate != default(string)) { multiSelect.TagTemplate(tagTemplate); }
    return multiSelect;
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From Telerik tech support,

> Generally speaking, this is not supported by the MultiSelect MVC
>   wrapper and its dataSource always expects a collection, but can be
>   achieved by overriding the reader.data function e.g.
>
> ```
> multiselect.dataSource.reader.data = function (data) { return data.values};
> ```